# ASP.NET MVC Core add logging for other projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to add logging to my MVC Core application. I read the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging

The problem is that I don't know how to add logging to my other layers in the solution.

### These are the projects I have in my solution:

- MVC Core - No special explanation, just mvc project. References: Common, BL.
- Common - This project contains all entities and interfaces. References: None.
- BL - Business logic - contains the "managers"/"services" - the layer between the ui and data layers. References: Common, DAL
- DAL - Data access layer - Contains the repositories. References: Common

I'm using the built-in mvc core dependency injection framework to inject the ILogger instance into the mvc controllers.

From what I understand, its not a good practice to share logger instance between clases, and each class should have its own logger instance.

What should I do to add logging into my BL and DAL layers?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can put the ILogger in the constructor of you classes and DI will inject it.  So if you have a class named Foo, it would look something like this FooI(ILogger<Foo> logger).  This is exactly what I am doing and it works great.

Comment: We share logger instances between classes. In fact, adding ILogger as a singleton to your DI pipeline is the same as sharing a logger...